# How to select data from a table based on 3 other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

Here are the tables and the relevant fields:

```
shapes:        shape_id, shape_value
trips:         shape_id, trip_id
stop_times:    trip_id, stop_id
stops:         stop_id, stop_value
```

now the logic flow:

I want to select **shapes_shape.value** where **shapes.shape_id = trips.shape_id**

**trips.shape_id** is selected where **trips.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id**

**stop_times.trip_id** is selected where **stop_times.stop_id = stops.stop_id**

finally **stops.stop_id** is selected where **stop_value < 5**

how can I query this ?

also worth mentioning: for every **stop_times.stop_id** there might be 20-50 rows with the same **stop_times.trip_id** (with other parameters in the columns different) same with **trips.trip_id** and **trips.shape_id**. How can I modify the database and the tables to make it easier for the server? how can I delete the rows if there are other rows with same 2 columns ?

Example of this in the stop_times table:

```
trip_id  arrival_time  departure_time  stop_id  stop_sequence
2147483647  05:26:30    05:26:30       8447          4
2147483647  05:36:30    05:36:30       8447          4
2147483647  05:46:30    05:46:30       8447          4
2147483647  05:56:30    05:56:30       8447          4
2147483647  06:06:30    06:06:30       8447          4
```

I am new to the SQL syntax and couldn't get the concept of join tables and generally complex select queries.

*Important to mention that each table contain 50,000-500,000 rows, while now i'm building the base of my app and want to just make it work I would be happy to receive any suggestion on how to improve the query further and just concepts for me to research later in the development (while the query you could provide me here are just simple and probably not that optimized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you have to use **JOIN** to join the tables with appropriate columns. Check below query:

Try this:

```
SELECT s.shape_value
FROM shapes s 
INNER JOIN trips t ON s.shape_id = t.shape_id
INNER JOIN stop_times st ON t.trip_id = st.trip_id
INNER JOIN stops ss ON st.stop_id = ss.stop_id
WHERE ss.stop_value < 5;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've implemented this query into my code but I got "500 Internal Server Error" after 3 minutes of no answer from the server (I run the server and the database from a virtual machine and it might be too weak) but there are several things that might cause this too: for every **stop_times.stop_id** there might be 20-50 same **stop_times.trip_id** (other parameters are different but for now I maybe can throw them out if its too demanding on the server) same with **trips.trip_id** and **trips.shape_id**. How I can make the query lighter on the server ? If I need to change the DB, how ?